# Get multiple $sums from single MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a schema that looks something like this (simplified to the relevant parts):

```js
{
    time: ISODate,
    data: {
        user: {
            username: String,
            ...
        },
        type: String,
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to aggregate the data per user and get counts of different "type" values. So assuming the following data:

```js
[
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'bob'}, type: 'value1'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'bob'}, type: 'value1'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'bob'}, type: 'value1'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'bob'}, type: 'value2'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'bob'}, type: 'value2'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'joe'}, type: 'value1'} },
    { time: ISODate(...), data: {user: {username: 'joe'}, type: 'value1'} }
]
```

I need to get the following info:

```js
[
    { username: 'bob', value1: 3, value2: 2 },
    { username: 'joe', value1: 2, value2: 0 }
]
```

The actual structure of the resulting data isn't nearly as important as just have the right info. How can I write an aggregate query to get this data?

Comment: What have you already tried to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to get the data you are looking for using [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) would be to use the `$push` operator in `$group` phase like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group":{
        _id:{username:"$data.user.username", 
        type:"$data.type"}, 
        count:{$sum:1}}
    }, 
    {"$group":{
        _id:"$_id.username", 
        values:{$push:{value:"$_id.type", count:"$count"}}}
    }
])
```

Here's the output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "joe",
                        "values" : [
                                {
                                        "value" : "value1",
                                        "count" : 2
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "bob",
                        "values" : [
                                {
                                        "value" : "value2",
                                        "count" : 2
                                },
                                {
                                        "value" : "value1",
                                        "count" : 3
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```